# comparing character to space in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, char

I'm completely new to C++, coming from a Java and Python background.

Eventually, for the program I need to write, I need to reverse the order of the words in a string. i.e. "Do or do not there is no try" becomes "try no is there not do or Do"

But right now, I'm just trying to put the individual words in an array/vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string x = "There is no knowledge that is not power";
    vector<string> myvector;
    string str = "";
    char spaceman = ' ';

    for( int a = 0; a < x.length(); a++)
    {
        if(x[a].compare(spaceman) != 0)
        {
            str.append(x[a]);
        }
        else
        {
            myvector.push_back(str);
            str = "";
        }
    }


    cout << myvector.at(0) << endl;

    cout << x[0] << endl; //A test on x

    return 0;
}
```

However, that returns the following warning and error messages(I'm using CodeLite, by the way):

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
for( int a = 0; a < x.length(); a++)
                             ^

error: request for member 'compare' in 'x.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((std::basic_string<char>::size_type)a))', which is of non-class type 'char'
if(x[a].compare(spaceman) != 0)
        ^

error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
str.append(x[a]);
               ^
```

What am I missing? I'm very unfamiliar with C++ as is. Changing the "spaceman" variable from char to string didn't do anything either.

Comment: Just a little advice: if you're iterating through a string's characters, use `for (const auto& c : yourString)`. It's a more modern way of doing it. Although it doesn't really make a difference in this case, it just looks nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Simply compare like-with-like, something like:

```
if(x[a] == spaceman)
{
    // ...
```

because `x[a]` is a `char` as is `spaceman`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you could build the vector simpler. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "There is no knowledge that is not power";
    std::istringstream is( s );

    std::vector<std::string> myvector( ( std::istream_iterator<std::string>( is ) ),
                                         std::istream_iterator<std::string>() );

    for ( std::string t : myvector ) std::cout << t << std::endl;
}
```

As for your code then in this for statement

```
for( int a = 0; a < x.length(); a++)
```

you compare signed integer a with unsigned x.length(). It would be correctly to write

```
for( std::string::size_type a = 0; a < x.length(); a++)
```

In this statement

```
if(x[a].compare(spaceman) != 0)
```

expression x[a] has type char. Fundamental types including char are not classes and have no methods.

And there is no append method in class std::string that has one parameter of type char. 
So instead of

```
str.append(x[a]);
```

there shall be

```
str.append(1, x[a]);
```